# How to give a Blob uploaded as FormData a file name?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, form-data

I am currently uploading images pasted from the clipboard with the following code:

```
// Turns out getAsFile will return a blob, not a file
var blob = event.clipboardData.items[0].getAsFile(), 
    form = new FormData(),
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
form.append("blob",blob);
request.open(
            "POST",
            "/upload",
            true
        );
request.send(form);
```

Turns out the uploaded form field with receive a name similar to this: Blob157fce71535b4f93ba92ac6053d81e3a

Is there any way to set this or receive this file name client side, without doing any server side communication?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

For Chrome, Safari and Firefox, just use this:

```
form.append("blob", blob, filename);
```

(see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append))

Comment: Where did you notice about this??? This is great! Is there any link regarding chrome versions' support of this?

Comment: BTW, this is in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/#interface-formdata

Comment: Also, i'm working on the firefox bug to fix this issue, i have already fixed it but i have some "style issues" https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=690659 (i'm currently out of time to fix this patch, so if anyone wants to pick it up i'm more than happy with it)

Comment: @Chiguireitor its still not fixed?

Comment: AFAIK not, my time has been lately a very scarce resource. As i said earlier, anyone who wants to pick up the slack is welcome.

Comment: Here is the "compatibility table" from MDN. Notice that as of this post, append with filename has shaky support on all browsers except Chrome and FF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#compat-desktop

Answer (score 50):

Adding this here as it doesn't seem to be here.

Aside from the excellent solution of `form.append("blob",blob, filename);` you can also turn the blob into a `File` instance:

```
var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify([0,1,2])], {type : 'application/json'});
var fileOfBlob = new File([blob], 'aFileName.json');
form.append("upload", fileOfBlob);
```

Comment: Problem is that you get the file/blob from the clipboard. What you're describing is related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251953/how-to-create-file-object-from-blob

Comment: doesn't work on IE cause it still doesn't support File constructor.

Comment: @Mahib [MDN's documentation on the `File` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File) suggests that it's supported from IE10 and up.

Comment: @RobertK.Bell, I practically checked on Edge and it didn't work :(, then I had to change back to blob constructor.

Comment: @Mahib You're right ― [issue #9551546 on Edge's tracker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9551546/) `File` constructor throws `Function Expected` exception

Comment: @Mahib IE doesn't like to support stuff very much, so we have dropped support for it post-2022.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're getting the data pasted to clipboard, there is no reliable way of knowing the origin of the file and its properties (including name).

Your best bet is to come up with a file naming scheme of your own and send along with the blob.

```
form.append("filename",getFileName());
form.append("blob",blob);

function getFileName() {
 // logic to generate file names
}
```

Comment: The question does not ask for the original filename. This answer is completely off target.

Comment: @NielsAbildgaard: Really? It is asking about assigning a filename, and doesn't the original filename qualify as a valid filename?

Comment: The answer does not answer the original question (other than "here's an alternative") and provides an answer to something that is not asked, and, frankly, off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

That name looks derived from an object URL GUID. Do the following to get the object URL that the name was derived from.

```
var URL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var object_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
URL.revokeObjectURL(object_url);
```

`object_url` will be formatted as `blob:{origin}{GUID}` in Google Chrome and `moz-filedata:{GUID}` in Firefox. An origin is the protocol+host+non-standard port for the protocol. For example, `blob:http://stackoverflow.com/e7bc644d-d174-4d5e-b85d-beeb89c17743` or `blob:http://[::1]:123/15111656-e46c-411d-a697-a09d23ec9a99`. You probably want to extract the GUID and strip any dashes.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it, but that should alert the blobs data url:

```
var blob = event.clipboardData.items[0].getAsFile(), 
    form = new FormData(),
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
  alert(event.target.result); // <-- data url
};
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Comment: This will alert blob as a data url indeed. What I want to receive/set is the file name attached to the form field when doing a form post upload.

Comment: Then I don't know of a way Without server side communication.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how the server on the other side is configured and with what modules for how it handles a blob post.  You can try putting the desired name in the path for your post.

```
request.open(
    "POST",
    "/upload/myname.bmp",
    true
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Google App Engine?
You could use cookies (made with JavaScript) to maintain a relationship between filenames and the name received from the server.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Google Chrome you can use/abuse the `Google Filesystem API` for this. Here you can create a file with a specified name and write the content of a blob to it. Then you can return the result to the user.

I have not found a good way for Firefox yet; probably a small piece of Flash like `downloadify` is required to name a blob.

IE10 has a `msSaveBlob()` function in the `BlobBuilder`.

Maybe this is more for downloading a blob, but it is related.