# Django model for storing multiple files in a single user profile

Tags: django, django-models

When a user logs into the database, he generates a WAV audio file (in the browser) which has to be stored in the database. The problem is that, everything is fine when I store the file for the first time. But, when I store after that, I get `IntegrityError`. Does anyone have the solution to this?

My current `models.py` is the following:

```
class InputFile(models.Model):

audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='audio_files')
input_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
rec_date = models.DateTimeField('date recorded', auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13333478/202168

Comment: Is your question about directly storing the files in the database as a blob? It is strongly discouraged for many reasons http://www.revsys.com/blog/2012/may/01/three-things-you-should-never-put-your-database/

Comment: @Anentropic I had seen that post before, but I wanted to know whether I can exploit the features in Django framework itself.

Comment: @arocks my final aim is to store as a WAV file (which I guess can be converted from blob)

Comment: as far as Django is concerned you're just uploading a file... the part you seemed stuck with is how to upload a javascript blob rather than an <input type="file"> field

Answer (score -1):

I would still recommend storing the user media as files. This way you can avoid storing large files in the database which is not only inefficient but also slow.

Furthermore, I would not recommend performing audio processing within the Django request-response. Try to use an asynchronous solution like [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Audio processing is quite similar to Video processing. You can get a lot of ideas from how video sharing sites like YouTube work. Once you upload a file, they notify you when the uploading and encoding is completed. This happens in a separate task queue.

The intermediate and final media files are again stored as files and served directly from the filesystem. By avoiding the database layer you can get a much more responsive application.