# How to save my generated javascript pdf file to my server's filesystem?

Tags: javascript, php, pdfmake

I'm using pdfmake to create my pdf and while it allows the user to open the pdf directly or download it to their computer, I'm not sure how I would go about generating the pdf and saving it to my server's file system.

From what I understand, there are plenty of security measures not allowing javascript to save data to file(s), so would sending it to my php backend be the only choice ? and how would i go about doing that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

(untested)
PHP:

```
<?
// pull the raw binary data from the POST array
$data = substr($_POST['data'], strpos($_POST['data'], ",") + 1);
// decode it
$decodedData = base64_decode($data);
// print out the raw data, 
echo ($decodedData);
$filename = "test.pdf";
// write the data out to the file
$fp = fopen($filename, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $decodedData);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

JS:

```
var docDefinition = {
  content: 'This is an sample PDF printed with pdfMake'
};

pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getBuffer(function(buffer) {
  var blob = new Blob([buffer]);

  var reader = new FileReader();
  // this function is triggered once a call to readAsDataURL returns
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('fname', 'test.pdf');
    fd.append('data', event.target.result);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'upload.php', // Change to PHP filename
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    }).done(function(data) {
      // print the output from the upload.php script
      console.log(data);
    });
  };
  // trigger the read from the reader...
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
});
```

Upload and receive code from [How can javascript upload a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333378/how-can-javascript-upload-a-blob).

Comment: You can actually get the base64 directly from pdfmake 'pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).getBase64(function(dataURL){//do something}'