# Jquery - CodeIgniter How to give file extension to a blob

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, blob

I have this situation where I'm sending an image blob via ajax to CI controller, which uploads it. The data is sent perfectly, but only when server tries to upload the file, it fails. I noticed it expects a file type with extension. Since its not provided, it fails. CI profiler shows the posted file as this:

```
Array
(
[name] => blob
[type] => image/png
[tmp_name] => D:xampptmpphpC5EA.tmp
[error] => 0
[size] => 634208
)
```

while it should be like this:

```
Array
(
[name] => featured.jpg
[type] => image/jpeg
[tmp_name] => D:xampptmpphpABDE.tmp
[error] => 0
[size] => 634208
)
```

I suspect this is where it fails. Here is my upload function code:

```
public function upload__image($path, $image){
    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    $config['upload_path'] = "./assets/images/$path";
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'png|jpeg|jpg|gif';
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
    $config['file_name'] = parent::getGUID();
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload("$image"))
    {
        $msg = $this->upload->display_errors('', '');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        return $data['file_name'];
    }
}
```

any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much. Should the fix be done on client side with Jquery or on server side? Kindly recommend optimal method as well.

**UPDATE**

```
$('#saveme').click(function() {
$croppMe.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob) {
var formData = new FormData();
var tid = $('#myid').val();
formData.append('croppedImage', blob);
formData.append('tid', tid);
$.ajax('upload.php', {
method: "POST",
data: formData,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
success: function (response) {
  if(response.Response == 200)
  {
    console.log("Upload successful"+response.Data);
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("some error occured");
  }
}
});
});
```

**UPDATE 2**
My php upload function returns this error, when I set it to display errors:

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: Please add the frontend code. Also this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333378/how-can-javascript-upload-a-blob

Comment: THank you @martinczerwi I'm updating my question with front end code.

Comment: @martinczerwi I have updated the question with the front end code. The problem is: even if I get to use that, as stated in a stackoverflow answer link you sent, how do I mix it down the blob with this name on server side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method [`FormData.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) has a third parameter that specifies the filename to use for the blob

```
formData.append('croppedImage', blob, 'featured.jpg');
```

Comment: Awesome @Musa this really worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Its works for me as well Thanks, @Zafar you should accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The method [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) has a second parameter mimeType. You should add the file type as a seccond parameter as well.