# Save Video.js recorder video on the server

Tags: html, webrtc, video.js

I am trying to save Video recorded through Video.js to save on server, below is my code

```
 <script>
    var player = videojs("myVideo",
    {
        controls: true,
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        plugins: {
            record: {
                audio: true,
                video: true,
                maxLength: 41,
                debug: true
            }
        }
    });

    player.on('startRecord', function()
    {
        console.log('started recording!');
    });
    player.on('finishRecord', function()
    {
         console.log('finished recording: ', player.recordedData);


    });

function uploadFunction()
{
 **//WRITE CODE TO SAVE  player.recordedData.video in specified folder//**
}   
</script>
```

Live Implementation : https://www.propertybihar.com/neo/videxp1/index.html

I was going through one the previously asked question, dint worked for me
[How can javascript upload a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333378/how-can-javascript-upload-a-blob)

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll down to the ["Upload" section on the README](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record#upload-data), you'll see this code snipped that does what you want, except for a streaming application:

```
var segmentNumber = 0;

player.on('timestamp', function() {
    if (player.recordedData && player.recordedData.length > 0) {
        var binaryData = player.recordedData[player.recordedData.length - 1];

        segmentNumber++;

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('SegmentNumber', segmentNumber);
        formData.append('Data', binaryData);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Test',
            method: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (res) {
                console.log("segment: " + segmentNumber);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

That is configured for continuously uploading the data but I've found I've had to make a few changes to it for my own setup:

- On Chrome 64 with VideoJS *6.7.3* and VideoJS-Record *2.1.2* it seems that `player.recordedData` is not an array but just a blob.
- I wanted to upload the video at a particular time, not streaming so I trigger the upload myself.

As a result, my upload code looks something like this:

```
if (player.recordedData) {
    var binaryData = player.recordedData.video;
    // ... Rest of that FormData and $.ajax snippet from previous snippet
}
```

If I don't do it this way, that check for existing data to upload always fails. I also trigger this code manually, rather than attaching it to the *"timestamp"* event of the `player` object. Of course, you'll need to have server side code that will accept this upload.