# Create virtual directory on page upload or park image file

Tags: javascript, html, virtual-directory

I'm not sure exactly how to word this so please bear with me.

I need to create something like a virtual directory with a visual boundary (either a folder icon or a rectangle with a border) on a web page so a person can drag an image from another page (in an iframe) and upload/park it on the page.

The reason I'm doing this is I'm working with a Caspio Cloud form (so I have no control over how image uploads are handled- it uses their simple 'Browse' to a file on your hard drive and uploads it upon submit). You cannot drag an image from a web page and 'drop' it on the Browse field. It needs the image to be a full file in a location.

What I'm trying to recreate is how one can drag/drop an image from a website onto the desktop and then drag/drop that image file into the Caspio Browse field and it uploads the image as it's supposed to (because the image file is at that point a regular file on the desktop).

I wanted to mimic the above but instead of dragging/dropping the image to the desktop drag/drop it to a virtual directory (or something like that) on the same web page the Caspio form is on. So upon dropping to this directory it would need to upload the full image file to the web page (but not the server- this is just a temp scenario, when the page refreshes the directory will be empty again). Then the user could drag/drop the image into the Caspio Browse field as if it were a 'normal' image file on the desktop.

So for this to work the virtual directory would need to be able to be read as a 'normal' location, as if it were a folder on the hard drive- that seems to be the only way the Caspio form can pull the image file.

This is a bit clunky in terms of getting an image off a web page and into the Caspio Browse/Upload field but it would significantly save time for the user because now they have to manually 'save as' an image in some location and then use the Caspio Browse button to find it. This would be a 'drag/drop from web page to virtual directory' and then 'drag/drop from virtual directory to the Caspio Browse field.'

Hope this makes sense and if anyone has any advice that'd be greatly appreciated. I'm working in basic html, javascript, and css..

Comment: Could you not offer the user an option to enter the URL of an image - use that URL in an `<img>` tag to create a thumbnail on the page, and then upload it as a [Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13333378/4746328) or a [dataImageURL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/934012/4746328) ??

Comment: I think the only option Caspio allows for an upload is an actual image file like a jpg or png file. That's why I was trying to 'create' the file on a temporary directory on the web page. It's a workaround at best but would be great if it's doable.