# how to compress file in sapui5 before uploading on server in instant upload?

Tags: sapui5

I want to compress a file before uploading it on server in sapui5 (image(png/jpeg/jpg)/pdf/). I want to upload a large files but i want to compress that file before uploading. Please suggest me solution ?

Comment: I don't think there are reliable ways to compress a file on the user's machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will not be able to do it with instant upload. Instead, you should obtain the file from the `change` event of the file uploader (check out the [change](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader.html#event:change) event, it has a files parameter).

You can then use that file object together with the [zip.js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) library to create an in-memory zip and save it into e.g. a Blob. Afterwards you simply send the blob into a POST request (e.g. look at [How can javascript upload a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333378/how-can-javascript-upload-a-blob)). Maybe you should also provide some file-uploading specific headers (like the `Slug`).