# How can I create/save a file from BLOB in php?

Tags: php, file, save, blob, wav

**What I did so far:**

Okay, so i create a blob file (wav content) and it is stored under *blob:http://localhost/cf6fefdc-352e-4cec-aef8-03af6d0d0ef6*.

When i put this URL into my browser, it plays the file.

**What i need to do**
I want to convert the blob into an actual file, that i want to store on my webserver.
I'm handing the blob object over to a php file via AJAX

```js
$.ajax ({
 type: "POST",
 url:"path/to/my/file.php",
 data: {thefile : blob} ,
     success: function(text) {
         console.log(text);
     },
     error:function(){
         console.log("Error")
     }
});
```

That works. If I print_r the variable it returns **[object Blob]** 

My PHP

```html
<?php
  $file = $_POST['thefile']; 
  print_r($file);
```

Can anyone tell me how I can convert and save the file to my server from there on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can javascript upload a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333378/how-can-javascript-upload-a-blob)

Answer (score 0):

In your file.php add this code

```
$filePath = 'uploads/' . $_POST['thefile'];


$tempName = $_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'];


    if (!move_uploaded_file($tempName, $filePath)) {

    echo 'Problem saving file: '.$tempName;
    die();
}

// success report
echo 'success';
```

Comment: you need to have "uploads" folder in your root directory

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created the folder (permission 777 just in case) but i get an error saying "<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: thefile in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/wp-content/themes/theme/file.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
Problem saving file: "

On line 6 it says:  $tempName = $_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'];

Comment: file_put_contents($path, $data); get that blobdata from ajax and use this method to save into your directory

Comment: okay, so thats what my php file looks like right now:
` $file = $_POST['thefile']; 
file_put_contents("test.wmv", $file);`

what it does is, it creates a text.wmv file, but it only has 13 byte, if I open it in a text editor, the content is "[object Blob]". so file is created, but still not the right way... any ideas?