# Audio recording in JavaScript on Chrome, always sends video/ogg to the server

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-mediarecorder

I have been trying to record audio in OGG format on Chrome and send it back to the server, but it always gets their in video/ogg format. Here is what I have:

Capturing audio:

```js
let chunks = [];
let recording = null;

let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
mediaRecorder.start();

mediaRecorder.onstop = function() {
    recording = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
}

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e){
    chunks.push(e.data);
}
```

Sending it to the server:

```js
let data = new FormData();
data.append('audio', recording);

jQuery.ajax(...);
```

The blob gets to the backend, but always in video/ogg!

Comment: It seems you're using jQuery.ajax(). so is your problem with jquery? please add the details of that call to the question.

Comment: also, have you considered using native javascript like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56006818/365237)

Comment: and as a third comment, why does it matter? ogg is just a container so it's the same ogg file regardless.

Comment: @eis I think the ajax code is irrelevant, be it jQuery or something else, it's the FormData object that gets sent, jQuery wouldn't change the mime type of the file ... or so I belive.

Comment: @eis It matters because the audio is sent to a seconds service that requires the mime to be audio/ogg not video/ogg. I though a bout converting the file on server, but that would be worse solution to a probably fixable issue on the front end.

Comment: is the problem just mime type sent or is there issue with contents as well? how do you see it's in video/ogg and not audio/ogg?

Comment: In fact I have not tested that. If you are saying that the content is what matters and I can change the mime to whatever works that would be great, but can I?!

Comment: not sure, but please test. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [kbumsik/opus-media-recorder](https://github.com/kbumsik/opus-media-recorder), solved the issue for me. A drop-in replacement for MediaRecorder.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the VideoTrack from your MediaStream:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("video");
const stop_btn = document.querySelector("button");
input.onplaying = (evt) => {
  input.onplaying = null;
  console.clear();
  const stream = input.captureStream ? input.captureStream() : input.mozCaptureStream();
  // get all video tracks (usually a single one)
  stream.getVideoTracks().forEach( (track) => {
    track.stop(); // stop that track, so the browser doesn't feed it for nothing
    stream.removeTrack( track ); // remove it from the MediaStream
  } );
  const data = [];
  const recorder = new MediaRecorder( stream, { mimeType: "audio/webm" } );
  recorder.ondataavailable = (evt) => data.push( evt.data );
  recorder.onstop = (evt) => exportFile( new Blob( data ) );
  
  stop_btn.onclick = (evt) => recorder.stop();
  stop_btn.disabled = false;
  recorder.start();  
};
console.log( "play the video to start recording" );


function exportFile( blob ) {
  stop_btn.remove();
  input.src = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
  console.log( "video element now playing recoded file" );
}
```

```css
video { max-height: 150px; }
```

```html
<video src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Volcano_Lava_Sample.webm" controls crossorigin></video>
<button disabled>stop recording</button>
```

And since StackOverflow's null origined iframes don't allow for safe download links, [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4rdpas2/) with a download link.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `mimeType` of the `MediaRecorder`. Otherwise the browser will pick whatever format it likes best to encode the media.

```
let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'my/mimetype' });
```

To be sure that the browser can actually encode the format you want you could use `isTypeSupported()`.

```
console.log(MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('my/mimetype'));
```

Chrome for example doesn't support `"audio/ogg; codecs=opus"` but supports `"audio/webm; codecs=opus"`. Firefox supports both. Safari none of them.

Once you've configured the `MediaRecorder` you can use its `mimeType` when creating the blob.

```
recording = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : mediaRecorder.mimeType });
```

Comment: Great, I will give it a try. But is there anyway to get audio/ogg out of chrome?! The 3rd party service I use requires OGG

Comment: Not that I know of. But it should be possible to write some code which unwraps the webm container to extract the opus audio.

Comment: Still sends it out as "video/webm"! This is just weird!

Comment: Sad but true: The MIME types MediaRecorder generates come from a small list. Chrome only does webm. Safari only does mp4. It's a real electropolitical mess.