# Uncaught TypeError: hammerit.get is not a function - jquery cropbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

getting this error when using jquery cropbox

Uncaught TypeError: hammerit.get is not a function
I need also Crop or download button

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/1.0.5/hammer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.6/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cropbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
    $(function () {
        var r = $('#results'),
            x = $('.cropX', r),
            y = $('.cropY', r),
            w = $('.cropW', r),
            h = $('.cropH', r);
        $('#cropimage').cropbox({
            width: 200,
            height: 200
        }).on('cropbox', function (event, results, img) {
            x.text(results.cropX);
            y.text(results.cropY);
            w.text(results.cropW);
            h.text(results.cropH);
        });
    });
</script>


<img id="cropimage" alt="" src="http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/img.jpg" />
    <div id="results"> <b>X</b>: <span class="cropX"></span>
     <b>Y</b>: <span class="cropY"></span>
     <b>W</b>: <span class="cropW"></span>
     <b>H</b>: <span class="cropH"></span>
    
    </div>
<a>Download</a>
```

Error image is:
[image]

Comment: Why use an anchor element when a button is more appropriate here? https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html vs https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html

Answer (score 1):

Update the jQuery and load it before any other jQuery plugin.

Also add the crop jQuery and CSS to the snippet.

For some reason does the newest hammer.js not work, so I left it

This works in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gjn6mvbt/) but possibly not on SO due to iFrame security

to upload instead of download use [How can javascript upload a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333378/how-can-javascript-upload-a-blob)

```js
function cropAndSave(src, x, y, w, h) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  //document.body.appendChild(canvas); // for testing
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx.drawImage(src, -x, -y);
  return {
    save: function(filename) {
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = filename;
        console.log("trying to download",filename);
        a.click();
      });
    }
  }
}

$(function() {
  let img = $("#cropimage")[0];
  let r = $('#results'),
    x = $('.cropX', r),
    y = $('.cropY', r),
    w = $('.cropW', r),
    h = $('.cropH', r);
  $('#cropimage').cropbox({
    width: 200,
    height: 200
  }).on('cropbox', function(event, results, img) {
    x.text(results.cropX);
    y.text(results.cropY);
    w.text(results.cropW);
    h.text(results.cropH);
  });
  $("#save").on("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    cropAndSave(img,
      x.text(),
      y.text(),
      w.text(),
      h.text()
    ).save("test");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/1.0.5/hammer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.6/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-cropbox@0.1.3/jquery.cropbox.min.js
"></script>
<link href="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-cropbox@0.1.3/jquery.cropbox.min.css
" rel="stylesheet">

<img id="cropimage" crossorigin="anonymous" alt="" src="http://acornejo.github.io/jquery-cropbox/img.jpg" />
<div id="results"> <b>X</b>: <span class="cropX"></span>
  <b>Y</b>: <span class="cropY"></span>
  <b>W</b>: <span class="cropW"></span>
  <b>H</b>: <span class="cropH"></span>

</div>
<a href="#" id="save">Download</a>
```

Comment: It's working fine. Thanks

Need one more help - I need CROP button instead of download button

Please suggest which code need to write

Comment: It gives a strange error when i addd the download

Comment: when I click on "Download" anchor tag getting error

1.html:58 Uncaught TypeError: URL.createObjectUrl is not a function
    at 1.html:58:38

Comment: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toBlob' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
    at Object.save (file:///D:/RND/Image-crop/1.html:57:28)

Comment: Spelling createObjectURL

Comment: It's working fine with if image has a Absolute url.

Comment: I need to send image to server instead of Download image. Please suggest.

Comment: You said `download button` 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333378/how-can-javascript-upload-a-blob

Comment: it's working fine with JPG, PNG images, but SVG is not working (just BLACK image cropped if I am using .svg)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=crop+save+svg+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com