# Is there a way to run AutoIT scripts on BrowserStack?

Tags: autoit, browserstack

Usually I  make use of AutoITscript to upload a file in the Windows dialog box. This is useful  while testing on Local Machines on any browsers. But,since I have now moved to use BrowserStack to tun my tests on cloud, I am finding it difficult to run the AutoIT script on the remote browser. Any help in this regards is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Note :I cannot directly enter the file path in the web UI as its disabled and the only way is to open the Windows dialog and browse to the actual path,which I used to do using the AutoIT script.

Comment: I think you should run two different tests, not one test for this. First one "is the form rendered correctly" and second one from the receiving side "do I receive files correctly". You can simulate an upload using `xhr` and blob/base64 data, so you don't have to mess with a real file.

Comment: @DanielW. Can you please elaborate more on how can we simulate an upload using xhr and blob/base64 data? Thanks

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293462/simulate-xhr2-file-upload 
Have a good new year m8!