# Blob javascript object in internet explorer browser changing the file name

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, blob

I am working on Blob object to upload files. The default file sent to server is 'blob'.
I want to overide it and set to the original file name.

I saw a similar **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664967/how-to-give-a-blob-uploaded-as-formdata-a-file-name)** in Stack Overflow and the answer suggested to use

```
form.append("blob",blob, filename);
```

But this would work only on chrome and FF.

Anybody knows how to do it in Internet Explorer Version 10+.

Thanks in Advance,
Br,
Rohit PAI

Comment: I would just send the name in another parameter `form.append("blobname", filename);`

Comment: @ Musa - Yes I agree with you. I dont have access to change the server side implementation and it works only on the file key present in the content deposition.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a File object using your blob object:

```
var temporalFile= new File([blob], 'correctName.txt'); 
form.append("blob", temporalFile);
```

Comment: You missed something here, the problem was that `FormData.append`'s `fileName` property wasn't working in IE (btw I'm unable to repro this isssue myself). According to [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=File) the `File()`constructor is not supported in any version of IE. That won't work as a workaround.