# How to load a PDF into a blob so it can be uploaded?

Tags: javascript, pdf, blob, plupload

I'm working on a testing framework that needs to pass files to the drop listener of a PLUpload instance. I need to create blob objects to pass inside a Data Transfer Object of the sort generated on a Drag / Drop event. I have it working fine for text files and image files. I would like to add support for PDF's, but it seems that I can't get the encoding right after retrieving the response. The response is coming back as text because I'm using Sahi to retrieve it in order to avoid Cross-Domain issues.

In short: the string I'm receiving is UTF-8 encoded and therefore the content looks like you opened a PDF with a text editor. I am wondering how to convert this back into the necessary format to create a blob, so that after the document gets uploaded everything looks okay.

What steps do I need to go through to convert the UTF-8 string into the proper blob object? (Yes, I am aware I could submit an XHR request and change the responseType property and (maybe) get closer, however due to complications with the way Sahi operates I'm not going to explain here why I would prefer not to go this route).

Also, I'm not familiar enough but I have a hunch maybe I lose data by retrieving it as a string? If that's the case I'll find another approach.

The existing code and the most recent approach I have tried is here:

```
    var data = '%PDF-1.7%����115 0 obj<</Linearized 1/L ...'
    var arr = [];
    var utf8 = unescape(encodeURIComponent(data));
    for (var i = 0; i < utf8.length; i++) {
        arr.push(utf8.charCodeAt(i));
    }

    var file = new Blob(arr, {type: 'application/pdf'});
```

Comment: xhr.responseType="blob"; ...; file = xhr.response;

Comment: did you try new Blob(data, {type: 'application/pdf'})?

Comment: I did try that. I'm pretty sure I tried @dandavis solution too but I'll try it again when I get a few minutes.

Comment: see the 2nd and 3rd examples on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data you're mimicking an old-school way of doing binary ajax in your posted code, but since IE8 that's been un-needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you were close.  I just did this for a site which needed to read a PDF from another website and drop it into a fileuploader plugin.  Here is what worked for me:

```
    var url = "http://some-websites.com/Pdf/";

    //You may not need this part if you have the PDF data locally already
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //console.log(this.response, typeof this.response);
            //now convert your Blob from the response into a File and give it a name
            var fileOfBlob = new File([this.response], 'your_file.pdf');

            // Now do something with the File
            // for filuploader (blueimp), just use the add method
            $('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {
                files: [ fileOfBlob ], 
                fileInput: $(this)
            });
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
```

I found help on the XHR as blob [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17682424/88732). Then [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35067907/88732) helped me with naming the File.  You might be able to use the `Blob` by itself, but you won't be able to give it a name unless its passed into a `File`.