# How do I convert a Blob URL to File (image file)

Tags: javascript, blob

I use a React component that converts an image to a blob URL. The URL looks like this: "blob:http://localhost:3000/78db8897-645d-4323-8865-8deaa9716a96". Appending it to a  works, it shows the image. But I want to be able to upload this string to the server as the file. I have a function I found here on SO but it doesn't work.

```
export function blobToFile(blobUrl, fileName) {
  const blob = new Blob([blobUrl], {
    lastModifiedDate: Date.now(),
    type: "image/png",
  });

  const file = new File([blob], fileName + ".png", {
    type: "image/png",
    lastModified: Date.now(),
  });
  return file;
}
```

Comment: do you see any errors in the debugging console?

Comment: no i dont see any errors. the file gets uploaded, but when i open it with my operating system, it doesnt open. so the conversion is wrong

Comment: is this supposed to work? i think the problem is with the blobUrl to Blob function

Comment: Have you googled yet? I searched and found two good posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251953/how-to-create-file-object-from-blob) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553617/convert-blob-to-file) that might help you. Otherwise, more information would be useful: Which browser do you use? Which version?

Comment: i figured it out. i found an answer on a chinese website lol

Comment: can you share your answer