# Blob in FormData is null

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm trying to send created photo in android via ajax via remote API. I'm using [Camera Picture Background](https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-camerapicturebackground) plugin.

Photo is created properly, I'm getting it via ajax `GET` request and encode it to base64 format. In debugging tool I can see image itself through `GET` request log.

Next I parse it base64 to Blob and try to attach it to `FormData`:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('photo', blobObj);
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'myUrl',
  data: fd,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false
}).done(function(resp){
  console.log(resp);
}). [...]
```

But when I send the `FormData` I see in debugger that `FormData` in request equals to: `{photo: null}`.

Btw. if I try to `console.log` my `blobObj` earlier, I see **it is** a blob, with its size, type properties and slice method - why it becomes a null after appending to `FormData`?

EDIT:

`console.log(blobObj);` gives:

`Blob {type: "image/jpeg", size: 50778, slice: function}`

EDIT2 - STEP BY STEP CODE:

I have url to local image, let's assume it is stored in `imagePath` variable.

First, I get this file and parse it to base64:

```
function base64Encode(){
  var CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
  var out = "", i = 0, len = str.length, c1, c2, c3;

  while (i < len) {
    c1 = str.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
    if (i == len) {
      out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
      out += CHARS.charAt((c1 & 0x3) << 4);
      out += "==";
      break;
    }
    c2 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
    if (i == len) {
      out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
      RS.charAt(((c1 & 0x3)<< 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
      out += CHARS.charAt((c2 & 0xF) << 2);
      out += "=";
      break;
    }
    c3 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
    out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
    out += CHARS.charAt(((c1 & 0x3) << 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
    out += CHARS.charAt(((c2 & 0xF) << 2) | ((c3 & 0xC0) >> 6));
    out += CHARS.charAt(c3 & 0x3F);
  }
  return out;
} 

function getFile(fileData){
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: fileData,
    mimeType: "image/jpeg; charset=x-user-defined"
  }).done(function(resp){
    var file = base64Encode(resp);

    dfd.resolve(file);
  }).fail(function(err){
    console.warn('err', err);
    dfd.resolve();
  });

  return dfd.promise();
};

$.when(getFile(imagePath)).then(function(resp){
    var fd = new FormData();

    resp = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + resp;

    var imgBlob = new Blob([resp], {type : 'image/jpeg'});

    fd.append('photo', img, 'my_image.jpg');

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'myUrlToUploadFiles',
      data: fd,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false
    }).done(function(resp){
      console.log(resp);
    }). [...]
});
```

Comment: Make blob like this  `var blob = new Blob([payLoad], {type : 'image/png'});`

Comment: I'm getting an error this time: `The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image`

Comment: How have you converted this base64-image into a blob? I use the filereader and its readAsArrayBuffer method as first param for the blob-constructor. And using a filename might help as well like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664967/how-to-give-a-blob-uploaded-as-formdata-a-file-name)

Comment: I've updated my question with details. I tried to use `FileReader` but when i was sending file it was also sent as FileData that equals in the end `{photo: null}` - so I've tried to solve this with code above.

Comment: Ok, sorry I used filereader for url-based images, for base64 strings atob should be used instead, it takes a base64 string and converts it directly to a blob. [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript). And If I were you I would use [readAsDataURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710147/image-convert-to-base64) of filereader or [todataurl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript) of canvas instead to convert an image into a base64 image.

Comment: But I don't want to use canvas - I would like to use only url to image which I don't know its size/dimenstions (width/height) (soultion in single function) - or should I anyway print on canvas given image every time?

Comment: Then I would use filereader and its readasdataurl method, in this way you do not need a ajax call and knowledge about its dimensions. this base64, coming out as a result of onload, you can convert into a blob by using atob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not done this recently, but this works with me. I hope it also works with you:

```
function getBase64ImageByURL(url) {
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      dfd.resolve(reader.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
  return dfd.promise();
}

function base64ToBlob(base64Image,toMimeType) {
  var byteCharacters = atob(base64Image.replace('data:'+toMimeType+';base64,',''));
  var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
    byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
  var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {
    type: toMimeType
  });
  return blob;
}



var imageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/49/Koala_climbing_tree.jpg";

getBase64ImageByURL(imageUrl).then(function(base64Image){
  var blob = base64ToBlob(base64Image,'image/jpeg');
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', blob, 'my_image.jpg');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://your_host/uploads/testupload.php',
    data: fd,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(res){
      console.log(res);
    },
    error:function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
});
```

On server-side(testupload.php):

```
<?php

    if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
    }
    else {
        $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$_SERVER["BASE"].'/uploads/'.'my_image.jpg');
        var_dump("image uploaded: ".$result);
    }

?>
```

It might be necessary to modify some read/write-permissions on a directory before *move_uploaded_file* succeeds in moving the uploaded image to this directory.

The function *getBase64ImageByURL* could already return a blob-object but by returning a base64-image you can show an user this image in a html-image-tag before uploading it for instance.

---

If there is  no need to show an user that image, then you can also shorten all steps:

```
function getBlobImageByURL(url) {
  var dfd = new $.Deferred();
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    dfd.resolve(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
  return dfd.promise();
}

getBlobImageByURL(imageUrl).then(function(imageBlob){
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('file', imageBlob, 'my_image.jpg');
  console.log(fd.get('file'));// File-object 
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://your_host/uploads/testupload.php',
    data: fd,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(res){
      console.log(res);
    },
    error:function(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
});
```

references to both modified functions *[base64ToBlob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)* and *[getBase64ImageByURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)*

Comment: hello, I've changed code to use canvas, but still, when sending, formData `file` (in my case - `photo`) is still `null`! :/ btw. I don't have access to server code.

Comment: With canvas you can crop the image before uploading but when you need the whole image I prefer filereader or the XMLHttpRequest object. I attached a shorter variante that just uses a XMLHttpRequest object. I tested this with chrome/FF and edge. Update your code, please.

Comment: Finally made it! Server-side code had an error! Thank You all for Your efforts - it was working since the beginning ;)