# How to do screenshot from webpage and download as excel ASP.NET CS

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

I am figuring out how to do a graph screenshot from webpage and download the graph as excel like this image

Graph excel https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtLHz.png]

Does anyone have any idea on that?

Alternatively, I tried downloading the graph by calling out the method but it does not have the data points, hence only have the border of the graph, which is wrong.

Hence, does anyone knows how to do screenshot? Thanks for your help!.

Comment: Just want to clarify, you want to capture the screenshot from webpage? Send it back to Server? And paste as Excel let user to download?

Comment: Yes! @Prisoner Am i able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For screenshot, you could follow this tutorial
[Capture a Screen Shot](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/)
For exporting graph to excel, refer to this
[Export Excel Chart](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-chart-export.htm)

Comment: Hi, does this apply for graph too? or only chart?

Comment: What library are  you using for generation of graph? Because Microsoft Excel library doesn't support Graph i think.

Comment: MS excel do support graph.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the full working solution, but I think it should able to guide you to code your own solution.

**Take a *screenshot* in web browser**

I should clarify that we cannot have any *screenshot*.  But we can generate a *picture* of a component as a *screenshot*.

```
$(function() { 
    $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;

                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    // If you okay with export as image, this is end
                    saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png"); 
                    // otherwise, comment above line, and post it back to server
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Full discussion can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24619118/1050927

***Paste image into Excel file***

After you post the blob (as file, [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9066159/1050927)), you can get that in server, and use Microsoft Office API or other API to create an Excel file and paste it into excel

***Return Excel file to user***

After you have done that, return the excel file back to user.